# Want to change my career to Physics from Software Development

Tags: phd, career-path, physics

I have always been fascinated by Physics But due to the CS hype in India took a miscalculated step to get my bachelor's in CS, After 4 years dedicated to a job in Software Development I want to change my career to physics I always used my weekends to brush up Maths and Physics topics during my job I now wish to pursue my dream of doing Ph.D. in physics from a foreign university ( MIT, ETH Zurich, etc ) meeting new people getting their perspective about a topic from a different angle, research and push the boundaries of science. I am 26 now and planning to get myself into a master's program in physics from India itself from IIT or HCRI (Harish Chandra Research Institute). It will take 2 years to complete my MSc I will be 28 by then. Is it still possible to get my Ph.D. abroad ???

Comment: Frankly, I don't know why you would think age 28 would be a problem. Would you please clarify the question?

Comment: @Nobody Thank you for replying . I meant that will I be accepted to a foreign Phd program after doing a masters in India Starting my masters in theoritical physics next year. The concern is that will my past CS career will hinder my chances to get a elite Phd program ( dreaming about the programs in MIT Columbia Tu Berlin etc ).

Comment: Your past choices won't hinder it per se, but you obviously would need to work harder than someone who was on that path from the start. Good luck.

Comment: @Lodinn Thank you .